# Jcrop messing up css position properties?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jcrop

I am using Jcrop with Bootstrap to crop an image inside a jumbotron (resizeable container for those unaware). When I attach Jcrop on a button click, everything is fine, but as soon as I call `jcrop_api.destroy()`, the image's position stays absolute/fixed and the jumbotron becomes distorted.

[image]

Any ideas why?